# Android FileOutputStream

Tags: android, android-intent

i am attempting to save an image file using "openFileOutput" and then adding that file to my intent with EXTRA_STREAM. but logcat keeps saying that file size is 0, i have the proper permission in my manifest.

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("p001.jpg", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
         File jpg = getFileStreamPath("p001.jpg");
            fos.close();
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);



         share.setType("image/jpeg");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Fail picture");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Epic fail!!!");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(jpg)); 
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Choose share method."));
```

updated code

```
private void HandleSMS() throws IOException {
         FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(R.drawable.p001, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
             File jpg = getFileStreamPath("p001.jpg");

            fos.close();
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);



         share.setType("image/jpeg");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Fail picture");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Epic fail!!!");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(jpg)); 
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Choose share method."));


        }
```

Comment: Can tel the location from where you are trying to fetch the image file.

Comment: in "openFileOutput("p001.jpg"" the p001.jpg is in R.drawable. for the uri.fromFile, im trying to fetch that image file by calling "getFileStreamPath("p001.jpg");" and getting its path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, do one thing instead  of the direct name use `R.drawable.NameOfTheImage`.

Comment: do you mean change openFileOutput("p001.jpg", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); to
openFileOutput("R.drawable.p001.jpg", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
that had no effect, still saying file size is 0 bytes

Comment: when i do this, i get this error "The primitive type int of R.drawable.p001 does not have a field jpg"

Comment: this is the code im using "FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(R.drawable.p001.jpg, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);" and this is the error it makes "The primitive type int of R.drawable.p001 does not have a field jpg"

Comment: Sorry it was by mistake, File name should be without ext.openFileOutput(R.drawable.p001, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); //without quote

Comment: took out the ext, and now it shows "The method openFileOutput(String, int) in the type ContextWrapper is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)" updated code is posted in original question.

Comment: im going to choose this as the right answer because your rly tried to help.but the correct answer was to use uri.prase and add ""android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" +" BEFORE you filename.

Comment: Thank you dude. I was searching that on google. Due to some important work. I wasnt able to reply.